# New .NET feature bundle and minification {version} wildcard isn't working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, bundling-and-minification

I am trying to use bundling with the {version} wildcard.
The bundles that contain {version} do not show in my rendered page's source code.
Is this feature limited to .Net 4.5?
I am only able to work with .Net 4.0 because of some infrastructure issues.

**UPDATE

My BundleConfig.cs file:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));      
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryui").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.*"));
```

The first bundle does not work the second bundle works correctly.

The jquery file path is /Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js and /Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js
Both files exist and if I use "*" the appropriate jquery file is brought in.

Comment: What did you try in your BundleConfig, what files did you have on disk, and what did you get in the rendered page?

Comment: And also, Bundling is fully supported in .NET 4.0 and .NET 4.5. There should be no feature differences between the two.

Comment: Are you using the final 1.0.0 RTM version of Bundling that was released a few weeks ago? The {version} feature wasn't available in the first few preview releases.

Comment: The version that shows in NuGet Packagemanager is 1.0.0 released last August. (Microsoft ASP.Net Web Optimization)

Comment: Oh oops sorry, you're right, 1.0.0 was from August. That's the RTM version.

Comment: Ok just because ... I unloaded the package and reloaded it and now things work as expected.

Comment: My guess would be that maybe there was an old DLL in there. Not sure why it would be messed up if NuGet said you had the right package though. But if it's case closed, I guess we're all good :)

Answer (score 0):

unloaded and reloaded the Web Optimization package via NuGet.